# How to change the Brand and Model name of Yu Yureka Plus?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow

This is a very common question for the Android Community, but trust me, I tried almost everything to change the Brand Name and Model name on my [Yureka Plus](http://www.gsmarena.com/yu_yureka_plus-7436.php) phone (running Cyanogenmod Nightly Build), but actually nothing worked.

Can anyone suggest any method which can perform it on my phone?

Here is what I tried:

1. I edited the build.prop in /system and changed ro.product.brand, ro.product.manufacturer etc. to samsung (original values-YU). And rebooted the phone, but then phone is not getting started. Stucks on the Logo screen.
2. Then I tried changing only Model name, and the same issue happened that phone got stuck on logo screen. Never gets boot-up.

Does anyone have solution for this, please help. Thanks.

Here is the original build.prop of my phone:

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=MOB30R
ro.build.display.id=YUREKA-userdebug 6.0.1 MOB30R 86209b5819 test-keys
ro.build.version.incremental=86209b5819
ro.build.version.sdk=23
ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL
ro.build.version.release=6.0.1
ro.build.version.security_patch=2016-07-05
ro.build.version.base_os=
ro.build.date=Sun Jul 24 08:26:46 PDT 2016
ro.build.date.utc=1469374006
ro.build.type=userdebug
ro.build.user=jenkins
ro.build.host=cyanogenmod
ro.build.tags=test-keys
ro.build.flavor=cm_tomato-userdebug
ro.product.brand=YU
ro.product.name=YUREKA
ro.product.board=MSM8916
# ro.product.cpu.abi and ro.product.cpu.abi2 are obsolete,
# use ro.product.cpu.abilist instead.
ro.product.cpu.abi=arm64-v8a
ro.product.cpu.abilist=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=arm64-v8a
ro.product.manufacturer=YU
ro.product.locale=en-US
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=msm8916
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=YUREKA
ro.product.device=YUREKA
# Do not try to parse description, fingerprint, or thumbprint
ro.build.description=YUREKA-user 5.1.1 LMY49J YOG4PAS8A4 release-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=YU/YUREKA/YUREKA:5.1.1/LMY49J/YOG4PAS8A4:user/release-keys
ro.build.characteristics=default
ro.cm.device=tomato
# end build properties

#
# ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
keyguard.no_require_sim=true
ro.carrier=unknown
media.aac_51_output_enabled=true
ro.sys.fw.dex2oat_thread_count=4
ro.config.max_starting_bg=8
ro.sys.fw.use_trim_settings=true
av.streaming.offload.enable=true
audio.offload.buffer.size.kb=64
audio.offload.gapless.enabled=true
audio.offload.min.duration.secs=30
audio.offload.pcm.16bit.enable=false
audio.offload.pcm.24bit.enable=true
use.voice.path.for.pcm.voip=true
ro.qualcomm.bt.hci_transport=smd
debug.composition.type=c2d
debug.mdpcomp.idletime=600
persist.hwc.mdpcomp.enable=true
persist.hwc.ptor.enable=true
debug.enable.sglscale=1
ro.opengles.version=196609
drm.service.enabled=1
vidc.enc.narrow.searchrange=1
ro.vendor.extension_library=libqti-perfd-client.so
ro.min_freq_0=960000
ro.min_freq_4=800000
persist.data.qmi.adb_logmask=0
persist.radio.apm_sim_not_pwdn=1
ro.telephony.call_ring.multiple=false
ro.use_data_netmgrd=true
ro.disableWifiApFirmwareReload=true
wifi.interface=wlan0
ro.hwui.texture_cache_size=72
ro.hwui.layer_cache_size=48
ro.hwui.r_buffer_cache_size=8
ro.hwui.path_cache_size=32
ro.hwui.gradient_cache_size=1
ro.hwui.drop_shadow_cache_size=6
ro.hwui.texture_cache_flushrate=0.4
ro.hwui.text_small_cache_width=1024
ro.hwui.text_small_cache_height=1024
ro.hwui.text_large_cache_width=2048
ro.hwui.text_large_cache_height=1024
ro.qc.sdk.audio.fluencetype=fluence
persist.audio.fluence.voicecall=true
persist.audio.fluence.voicerec=false
persist.audio.fluence.speaker=false
persist.camera.cpp.duplication=false
persist.camera.hal.debug.mask=0
persist.data.target=dpm1
persist.radio.multisim.config=dsds
ro.config.always_show_roaming=true
rild.libpath=/system/vendor/lib64/libril-qc-qmi-1.so
ril.ecclist=000,08,100,101,102,110,112,118,119,120,122,911,999
ro.telephony.default_network=9,1
ro.error.receiver.system.apps=org.cyanogenmod.bugreport
ro.rommanager.developerid=cyanogenmodnightly
ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-micromax
ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
ro.url.legal.android_privacy=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html
ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist=GoogleGuest
ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode=1
ro.com.android.dateformat=MM-dd-yyyy
ro.com.android.dataroaming=false
ro.build.selinux=1
persist.sys.dun.override=0
ro.cm.build.version.plat.sdk=6
ro.cm.build.version.plat.rev=0
media.sf.omx-plugin=libffmpeg_omx.so
media.sf.extractor-plugin=libffmpeg_extractor.so
persist.sys.root_access=0
ro.cm.version=13.0-20160724-NIGHTLY-tomato
ro.cm.releasetype=NIGHTLY
ro.modversion=13.0-20160724-NIGHTLY-tomato
ro.cmlegal.url=https://cyngn.com/legal/privacy-policy
ro.cm.display.version=13.0-20160724-NIGHTLY-tomato
ro.config.notification_sound=Argon.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=Helium.ogg
ro.config.ringtone=Orion.ogg
persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2=libart.so
dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.variant=cortex-a53
dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.features=default
dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant=cortex-a53
dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features=default
dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold=500
net.bt.name=Android
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt
ro.build.expect.trustzone=TZ.BF.3.0.R2-00034
ro.expect.recovery_id=0x03b923ae91dc2249b4b7bd9e10ad2a7646f0fd13000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: What's the purpose of changing the brand and model name may I ask?

Answer (score 0):

This means this CyanogenMod package is meant for multiple device models of the same codename, in your case, "tomato". CM automatically determines what model your device actually is and displays the corresponding model.

While I don't know how to manipulate that behavior, you can easily override that by adding a field to build.prop:

```
ro.product.model=MODEL_YOU_WANT_TO_SPOOF_AS
```

Save and reboot.

This is verified to work on my own CM13-running device (which also has the one codename VS multiple models situation), so I guess it'll also work on yours.